# Find a solid of revolution whose volume is 72π and whose surface area is 36π.

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, solid-of-revolution

I have tried setting up multiple systems of equations using many known volumes but I always seem to come up short. My last attempt was a hollow cylinder but that leaves you with three unknowns in only two sim. equations (for V and S.A). Can anyone help?

Comment: If you have three unknowns and only two equations, you can choose the value of one of the unknowns arbitrarily. This problem doesn’t have a unique solution — you have some freedom of choice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @bubba I overlooked that! Will retry it

Comment: @Brozovic The problem is only giving us a volume and surface area and asking us to find any random solid of revolution that would fit these measurements. I would assume that entails finding dimensions and its axis of rotation.

Comment: What are the three variables you use when considering a hollow cylinder? A cylinder is described completely by its height and radius.

Comment: As least for bounded shape, this is impossible. This violates the [isoperimetic inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#On_a_sphere) for 3-dimenion: $A^3 \ge 36\pi V^2$.

Comment: @achillehui Bless you for reassuring me that I didn't just suddenly go *retarded*.  I posted an answer to this problem, received valid criticism that forced me to delete my answer, and then spent over an hour unsuccessfully trying to conjure an example that remedied the 
 oversight in the answer that I posted.

Comment: @Taladris If the cylinder is hollow, you have to consider both the inner and outer radii.  This is similar to dimensioning a *thick pipe*.

Answer (score 2):

A cylinder of radius $R$ and height $h$ can be obtained by rotating the graph of $f(x)=R$, $0\le x\le h$ about the $x$-axis so it is a solid of revolution.

Its volume is $V=\pi R^2 h$ and its surface area is $S=2\pi Rh$. Then $V/S=R/2=2$ so $R=4$. Therefore, $h=9/2$.

**Note:** Usually, in Calculus, the surface area does not include the bounding surfaces (obtained by rotating the endpoints of the graph of $f$). If these surfaces should be included, then $S=2\pi Rh+2\pi R^2h=2\pi R(R+h)$. Since $V=72\pi$, we get $h=\frac{72}{R^2}$ so by substituting in $S$, we get the cubic equation

$$R^3-18R+72=0$$

It does not have any positive solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Does that leave the door for any other shapes to work though?

Comment: You need to also consider the top/bottom circles for the area of the cylinder.

Comment: @PC1: see my note

Answer (score 1):

There should be many closed curves satisfying the given constraints.

[image]
If $A$, $C$, $R_a$, and $R_c$ are the area, circumference, distance from axis to area centroid, and distance from axis to circumference centroid, respectively, we have
\begin{align}
R_a A=36\\
R_c C=18\\
\text{no part of red region cuts the axis}
\end{align}

I have tried choosing the red region as a circle as well as a rectangle, they are not possible. Other configurations are left for others.  Calculus of variations might help.

Comment: The centroids for each of the 2 theorems are not the same - one is with respect to the area and the other one to the perimeter.

Comment: @PC1 A good point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use [Pappus's centroid theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) for this purpose.

I will take a torus for example, with a centroid at a distance $R$ from the origin axis. Let's say that my torus radius is $r$. So using the 2 theorems, I find that the area $A$ and the volume $V$ are:

$$A = (2\pi R)(2\pi r)$$
$$V = (2\pi R)(\pi r^2)$$

From your hypothesis, $\frac V A = 2$ so $r=4$, and we can find from there that $R=\frac 9{4\pi}$. There might be other ways to find another solution.

EDIT:

Actually $r>R$ so I don't thinks the solution works. It might be that there is no such solid in the way I tried to solve it...

Comment: This is not a correct solution - I will leave it as it provides some hints on how to solve it though.

Comment: So does r have to be > R according to the theorem? It is the first time I come across it and the wikipedia is a bit hazy.

Comment: @mbstackbm the theorem doesn't state anything but the problem is that the torus section width overlaps itself. It's too wide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basic idea described by @PC1, based on Pappus’ theorems. But use a cone instead of a torus. I think that will work.